# What exactly does $(...).map() return?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given this:

```
<a href="1">1</a>
<a href="2">2</a>
```

Here is a function to return an array of href values:

```
e = $('a').map(function(v) { return $(this).attr('href'); });
console.log(e);
```

But it gives

```
["1", "2", prevObject: x.fn.x.init[2], context: document, jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

How can I modify this to only return a raw array ["1", "2"]?

Comment: As your `console.log` points out, those are not your href values.

Comment: That's why you should *never* completely trust the console output (at least `console.log`, `console.dir` should be fine). Since a jQuery object is an *array-like* object, `console.log` displays it as array. Other browser might show a different output.

Comment: OK fair call.  Any suggestions on how to do this to return a raw array?

(Have modified my question to reflect David's point)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is because [`jQuery.fn.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) returns a new jQuery Object, you should use [`jQuery.fn.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get an array:

```
var a = $('a').map(function(v, node) { 
    // v is the index in the jQuery Object, 
    // you would maybe like to return the domNode or the href or something: 
    // return node.href;

    return v; 
}).get(); // <-- Note .get() converts the jQuery Object to an array
```

---

**Micro optimization:**

If you look at the source code for `jQuery.fn.get` you can see that it points you to [`jQuery.fn.toArray`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/):

```
function ( num ) {
    return num == null ?

        // Return a 'clean' array
        this.toArray() :

        // Return just the object
        ( num < 0 ? this[ this.length + num ] : this[ num ] );
}
```

So you can also call:

```
$('a').map(...).toArray();
```